# Adb server not responding

Tags: android, adb

I am a Android newbie. I guess I might be doing something stupid here. I have started the Virtual Device and I see that `adbd` daemon is running from the Terminal Emulator. When I run `adb devices` I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * 
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon * 
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

No other process is using port 5037. What am I doing wrong? Here are the packages I have installed -

```
1) Android SDK Tools, revision 10
2) Android SDK Platform-Tools, revision 3
3) SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 1
```

Comment: You can check out in the Windows Logs if there are some conflicts when staring the adb program. "My Computer"->right click, "Manage", "Event viewer" (XP). It's good to check Application and System events.

Comment: I am running Windows 7. Are there any known conflicts for it?

Comment: I haven't heard of such conflicts; I also run windows 7; but in the logs you can see if there is more info about your problem. You can also upgrade to the latest Android SDK as olamotte suggests (in newer versions of the SDK, the adb program is in platform-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the Windows Firewall and its working like magic. I am connected to the Internet through WiFi. If you are not behind a proxy and are still unable to access the Internet through a wireless link via the emulator, go to Device Manager and disable your LAN card.

Answer (score 36):

This will occur normally,if abd is not able to launch properly and didn't exit when adb kill-server is executed.

So if in Windows 
1. Go to Task Manager (CTRL+ALT+DEL)
2.look for adb.exe and end the process.
Now restart the emulator ,should work properly.

additionally you can close and launch the development environment also (eg: Eclipse or NetBeans).

Comment: This answer must be accepted.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect the problem is cause of many adb instances (in windows) , i usually face this problem cause i don't turn off my system so the adb process may not end properly.

So open task manager choose Process tab just search for adb.exe, right click on it and choose **End Process Tree** rather than just *End Process*

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, it seems that my security solution was blocking adb.exe

Answer (score 1):

this is not the right folder for adb : lately adb has moved from /tools to /platform-tools in the sdk folder.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the security program is blocking `adb.exe`, so go to the adb file path and open adb's properties, then check the `Run this program as administrator` setting.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the process adb.exe starts when i connect the phone, and then when I adb devices then I have your problem, and killing the process does not help it is resurrecting like a stubborn zombie, as long as the phone is connected.
so my solution was to disconnect the phone, then kill adb.exe process, then start it by adb devices and connect the phone
After that when    i command adb devices   i ma getting the same prompt about killing adb out of date, but this time on the second line is * daemon started sucessfully*

win xp
htc sensation 
the new eclipse adt sdk bundle from google so i suppose up to date.

Comment: the above solution did not work after all but i have found the problem it was htc sync application resurrecting adb.exe so i have uninstalled the htc sync and the problem is sorted

Answer (score 1):

I found there was a process call "Tadb.exe" in Windows Task Manager.
I guess Tadb.exe is a similiar adb application of Tencent. Because I got an alert of "android device detected by QQ" after I install the last version of Tencent QQ2013 Beta5 (6970) yesterday.

After I killed the Tadb.exe, the original adb.exe of Android SDK works again.

You can see the detailed proecss to solve this problem here:
[adb cannot run, adb server is out of date](http://rangerway.com/way/2013/09/30/android-programming-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental reason is because the 5037 port on your machine to be occupied by a process, not only Android devices can not use adb connection ios device not use iTunes.

Can query process and close it, netstat / a / o maybe can help you to take up to 5037 ports.

To windows7 the LogsAndAlerts service will occupy port 5037.

Comment: Please post in English. Google Translate does a fairly good job of translating this.

Answer (score 0):

As I have tried as follow by combining omni.present's method , and finally emulator works fine.
firstly I stop adb.exe process in the task manager
then I stop and start eclipse