# Why every time after running application new android emulator is started and none of them are shown in DDMS section

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

First my emulator is too slow to work properly. I'm already frustrated because of it. So I closed that emulator and stated another(by running the application). But now my emulator is not showing in DDMS and every-time I run the application it creates new emulator rather than using existing. So I'm not able to run the application on emulator. If I connect a device then the device is showing in DDMS and working properly, but not my emulator.
And please don't tell me to restart emulator, eclipse etc. Because, already a lot of times I have tried it(even restarting PC), but its useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the emulator via the command line with the parameter `-verbose`, might give you some information on the issue.

Comment: Google API(Google Inc) - API Level 16 : emulator And  android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" in manifest

Comment: Sorry, I mean what Host OS are you running, windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: Try using the “Reset adb” option from the DDMS Devices view menu, or restarting the server at the command line:
1 adb kill-server
2 adb start-server

If that does not work, then try this instead:
Start Emulator, wait for it to come up, then type the following
1 adb kill-server
2 adb logcat -c

Comment: Do you have any command line experience, if so try running the above commands. You will need to navigate to the directory that adb.exe is located before running commands.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18979/discussion-between-john-and-shirish-herwade)

Comment: @jOk sorry, I made your answer unexpected from accepted, because still the problem is as it is

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by going to wards DDMS-> reset adb..

Comment: Seems to be imcomplete

Comment: Sorry for that... when ever this problem arises for me I go to DBMS, then Devices(if it is empty) and in that go for options and try to reset DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the emulator speed is too slow. If You want to start the same emulator, You may choose it explicitly. 
If you are using eclipse Right click your project -> Properties-> Run Debug Settings -> Click on your project name -> Edit -> and choose 'Always prompt to pick device' . 
So now everytime you build your project, you can choose the same emulator. 
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks for the advice, but the problem is my emulator is not showing in DDMS means, it is also not shown in the available running devices when it is prompted to choose device :)

Comment: Okay. I assume that the emulator is not listed in the AVD manager. Try this : If you are using linux or mac osX. 0. open terminal 1. Become superuser. 2. Go to ur android-sdk platform tools directory. 3. Do adb kill-server 4. Then adb start-server.

Comment: again thanks for advice, but i'm using windows xp 32 bit. So I think above suggestions can't be tried by me :) :)

Comment: 1. Go to Task Manager (CTRL+ALT+DEL) 2.look for adb.exe and end the process. Now restart the emulator ,should work properly. taken from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343670/adb-server-not-responding

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the path to `platform-tools` from my `bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OSx, you need to go Run-> Edit Configuration and you need to tick use the same devices for future