# Android Studio ADB not responding

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

[It is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79J3q.png)   Normally ı was using an Android Studio without any error. But now I get an error message ;
"ADB not responding.If you'd like to retry,then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click Restart"

But ı couldn't find adb.exe file in platform-too     [And ı didin't find adb.exe in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIq6j.png). 
How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adb server not responding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343670/adb-server-not-responding)

Comment: refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059334/adb-not-responding-you-can-wait-more-or-killabd-exe-process-manually-and-clic

Comment: There is no adb.exe file in Windows Task Manager too. @FireSun

Comment: I tried to Uncheck and check for Enable ADB Integration. But it doesn't work. Also,when i  run the command adb kill-server,i am getting a message like this "adb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch files" @Aashvi

Comment: Can you post complete error log.

Comment: I re-installed android studio again , but nothing changed. http://i.stack.imgur.com/YIq6j.png  I don't have a adb.exe file.  @FireSun

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of adb to Environment Variables in System settings . To find path of adb , try

[image]